# Audio buffer error when headphones plugged in

Tags: c++, ios, audio, novocaine

I'm using Novocaine to play audio within an app, and I'm consistently getting a crash after the following steps:

1. Open app on iPhone with no headphones plugged in
2. Begin audio playback in app
3. Plug in headphones

The app crashes on the line `outData[i*stride] = mData[whichChannel][idx];` in the following function:

```
void RingBuffer::FetchData(float *outData, SInt64 numFrames, SInt64 whichChannel, SInt64 stride)
{
    int idx;
    for (int i=0; i < numFrames; ++i) {
        idx = (int)((mLastReadIndex[whichChannel] + i) % (mSizeOfBuffer));
        outData[i*stride] = mData[whichChannel][idx];
    }

    mLastReadIndex[whichChannel] = (mLastReadIndex[whichChannel] + numFrames) % (mSizeOfBuffer);

    mNumUnreadFrames[whichChannel] -= numFrames;
    if (mNumUnreadFrames[whichChannel] <= 0) mNumUnreadFrames[whichChannel] = 0;

}
```

In the header file, `mData` is declared as `float **mData;` and the error message in the editor is "AURemoteIO::IOThread(14): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)."

If I type `po mData[whichChannel][idx]` in the console, I get the message "error: Couldn't apply expression side effects : Couldn't dematerialize a result variable: couldn't read its memory."

What's happening here and how can I avoid it? As an Objective-C/Swift developer, these are strange waters for me, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks for reading!

EDIT: Additional debugging information at the time of crash:

```
numFrames=1024
whichChannel=1
stride=2
idx=6 // though it's been several different numbers before at the time of crash
```

Comment: You need to run this in a debugger, set a breakpoint on `outData[i*stride] = mData[whichChannel][idx];` and watch the values of `stride`, `whichChannel`, and `numFrames`. We can't see what those values are since they are passed into the function.

Comment: Hi @JamesMoore, thanks for the comment. Please see the edit above.

Comment: @Rogare did u get rid of the issue? Even I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Tthe variable whichChannel is the culprit, when we play a song on speakers and connect the headphones afterward, it crashes as soon as whichChannel becomes 1, i tried to hardcode it to 0 for such scenario and the crash stopped but the audio became distorted! in novocaine.mm, change line 901 and 902 to this

//    self.numOutputChannels = newNumChannels;
        self.numOutputChannels = 1;

this will fix the issue :)

Comment: Even set for 1 audio is distorted and playing bit faster then actual. Any idea about it?

Comment: it worked great for me then, haven't looked into it since then so no such idea, sorry